# If I said the blessings over already lit candles, have I fulfilled my hannukah mitzvah?

Tags: halacha, blessing, chanuka, lighting

On the first night of Hannukah, I got home from work after dinner, and my wife had lit the candles and said the blessings with the kids.

I said all three blessings over the already lit candles.  In doing so, did I fulfill my hannukah mitzvah for that night?

Would it have been better for me to blow out the candles and relight by saying the blessings?

Does it matter that I am a man? (I ask because lighting the shabbat candles is traditionally a woman's mitzvah)

Comment: Longdaysjourneyintocode,  and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around and find other content of interest, perhaps including our 180+ other [tag:chanuka] questions. Also, don't miss our new *Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?* booklet: http://s.tk/miyodeya

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Keep in mind that you should treat any [practical halachic advice you get here as if it came from a crowd of your friends](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. I hope to see you around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the mitzvah to light has already been fulfilled by your wife, assuming she's Jewish, as per answers and comments to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50452/flying-during-channukah-candle-lighting), and you have already gained the mitzvah via your wife's lighting.

The fact that others in the household light the candles is what is called *hiddur mitzvah* - enhancing the mitzvah. If you're following this rule, you have to light them, and you would make the blessings.

The blessing for the Chanukah candles includes the words "to light", meaning that this involves an action. Saying the blessing on already lit candles is not performing any action, and hence is not performing any mitzvah, and, **possibly**, could be a *bracha levatalah*, a blessing said in vain.

Comment: @msh210 was that really necessary? Don't we generally assume that questions about people making berachot are about Jews doing so?

Comment: What is the possibility that it is not a bracha levatalla?

Comment: @IsaacMoses it was absolutely not necessary and we do so assume (and I assume the same is true here) but it does improve the answer post IMO.

Comment: @msh210, I am afraid that it could be interpreted as an expression of unwarranted suspicion of OP.

Comment: @msh210, it does rub me the wrong way a bit. I came from a mixed marriage(If people want to have discussions on that, please have them elsewhere), and comments like that can come across as antagonistic, even if not meant as such.

Comment: @Longdaysjourneyintocode, it certainly was not meant as antagonistic -- merely as informative -- and I'm sorry for any misunderstanding. I'm glad I made the edit, though, since, as you've just indicated, the information I added is in fact relevant.

Comment: Oh, wait, you said "came" not "come". Belay the last sentence of my previous comment, then. I am still glad I made the edit, though, as it's informative anyway.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, Longdaysjourneyintocode, note that SE pages are meant for future visitors as much as for the asker. I did not mean to impugn the latter.

Comment: Rabbi Genack in [Torah To-Go Series• Kislev 5775](download.yutorah.org/2014/1053/Chanuka_To-Go_-_5775.pdf)
quotes the Gemoro  Shabbos 23a re: someone who **sees** Chanukah lights "Rav Yehuda said: On the first day, one who sees [Chanukah lights] recites two [blessings] and one who lights recites three. 

Mishnah Berurah 676:6, rules that if family members
already lit on behalf of someone, that individual should not recite a beracha upon seeing Chanukah lights because of the rule that one should refrain from reciting a
beracha whenever there is a doubt). So he cannot even say "she'oso nissim"!